# Simplest way to define a route that returns a 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, http-status-code-404

I've got a requirement to specify a named route in a Ruby on Rails project that returns the public/404.html page along with the 404 server response code.

Leaving it blank is not an option, please don't question why, it just is :) It absolutely must be a named route, or a map.connect entry would do.

Something like this would be great:

`map.my_named_route '/some/route/', :response => '404'`

Anyone have any idea what's the easiest way to do something like this.  I could create a controller method which renders the 404.html file but thought there might be an existing cleaner way to do this.  Looking forward to any responses - thanks,

Eliot

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can route to a rack endpoint (rails 3) that vends a simple 404:

```
match 'my/route', to: proc { [404, {}, ['']] }
```

This is particularly handy, for example, to define a named route to your [omniauth endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531263/omniauth-doesnt-work-with-route-globbing-in-rails3):

```
match 'auth/:action', to: proc { [404, {}, ['']] }, as: :omniauth_authorize
```

Comment: This is a good approach for any response that does not need a controller. It is still less efficient than doing this in Apache/nginx.

Comment: In Rails 4 use the :to option, e.g. `get '/apple-touch*str', to: proc { [404, {}, ['']] }`

Comment: @mmell That won't work, you have to do this:   `get '/:str', to: proc { [404, {}, ['']] }, constraints: { str: /apple-touch.*/}`

Answer (score 3):

In your routes.rb:

```
map.my_404 '/ohnoes', :controller => 'foobar', :action => 'ohnoes'
```

In `FoobarController`:

```
def ohnoes
  render :text => "Not found", :status => 404
end
```

If you need to render the same 404 file as a normal 404, you can do that with `render :file`.

See [ActionController::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html) documentation for examples.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you do this in Apache/nginx where you use mod_rewrite (or however nginx does rewrites) to link to a non-existent page or instead send a 410 (Gone, no longer exists) Flag?

Anyway, if you want the rails app to do this, I think the way is as you suggested, create a named route to an action that does a `render(:file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html", :status => 404)`

Answer (score 1):

Slighly shorter version than the previous answers to 404 any get in one line.
`get '*_', to: ->(_) { [404, {}, ['']] }`