# OmniAuth doesn't work with Route Globbing in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, omniauth, glob

I am trying to follow the Railscast 241 [Simple OmniAuth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth)  and it works fine unless I have Route Globbing at the end of `/config/routes.rb`:

```
match '*uri' => "posts#index"
```

If I request `/auth/twitter` with the globbing then OmniAuth does nothing:

```
Started GET "/auth/twitter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-03 19:17:44 +0200
  Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"uri"=>"auth/twitter"}
Rendered posts/index.html.haml within layouts/application (9.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 103ms (Views: 14.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Without the globbing route it authenticates correctly.

Is there a way to have both the route globbing and OmniAuth?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The OmniAuth process](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/7b3644f/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L128-133) is to provide the following functionality when a `/auth/:provider` URL is called:

1. Pass the request to the underlying Rack/Rails app as if OmniAuth wasn't there;
2. Determine whether or not the underlying application generated a 404;
3. If it did, invoke the actual OmniAuth functionality.

Since you are essentially matching *everything* using your route globbing, your application will never give 404's, and OmniAuth cannot do it's job. I see two immediate options.

### Match OmniAuth Routes to a 404 Manually

Add a new route as follows:

```
match '/auth/:provider' => 'omniauth#passthru'
```

Then create a controller and action that generates a 404:

```
class OmniauthController < ApplicationController
  def passthru
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
  end
end
```

### Determine 404 Status in the Glob Route

I assume that your glob route will search for a post matching the URL somehow; you can take misses (e.g. when `PostsController#index` can't find a post) and generate 404's then.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if @posts = Post.find_by_current_url_or_whatever
      render 'index'
    else
      render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks! Now I see how it works. I have set the routes as you suggest with minor changes. Could you comment them (see my answer) if I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified [suggestion of Brandon Tilley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531263/omniauth-doesnt-work-with-route-globbing-in-rails3/5534000#5534000):

```
# config/routes.rb
match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
match 'auth/*rest' => 'application#omniauth'
match '*uri' => 'posts#index'

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def omniauth
  render text: 'Authentication', status: 404
end
```

Comment: Don't forget that OmniAuth uses other routes, like `/auth/failure`, to indicate a failed auth (e.g. the user declined the permissions on Facebook, etc). Using these routes, that URL would be eaten by `application#omniauth`.